# Python Patch requests returning 403 status Code against SNOW Record

Tags: python, python-requests, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I wanna do some integration against ServiceNow (SNOW) record. I managed to integrate by using GET requests and returning Status code 200 which means successful.

However, when I wanna do Patch request to edit or update the record, it is returning status Code 403, which means Forbidden.

How can I fix this and where should I check?

Comment: Are you sure your request is authenticated properly?

Comment: yes, I am sure. I am using the same authentication as I used on GET requests method that returning 200 (Successful). I have also purposely used false credentials to test on the status code. the GET requests returning 401 (Unauthorized), while the Patch requests still returning 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Maybe the account does have read, but no write permission in the table?

Comment: I have checked on that, the account I used able to submit new record on that table and also able to update/key-in directly. Web_service_access also has been ticked.

Comment: Are there any more details in the server's response? A status text, a body?

Comment: Hi, here is the details after I print the output.text:

Content: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /api/now/table/sc_req_item/2a2851fe88709010b9120e9b506dd9a9
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say anything other than "this is a permission issue", double-check the API rights of your account.

Comment: Yep, I think the same too. Thanks for ur advice.Will escalate this to SNOW Team side then.

Comment: Well, good luck! :)

Comment: Hi, 

They replied maybe have security issue related to ssl cert as the result of the python script also included ssl-warning. 

Based on your knowledge and experience, is this ssl cert really required and related to this issue?

Comment: Possibly. What is the warning?

Comment: Here is the warning: "Unverified https request is being made to the host domain.host.com. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised"